# Why is the algebraic torus an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, toric-varieties

I am reading [*Toric Varieties*](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pragmatic2010/CoxLittleSchenckJan2010.pdf) by Cox, Little, and Schenck. I am stuck on the definition an algebraic torus, given in Part 1.1, page 10, which states:

> The affine variety $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ is a group under componentwise multiplication. A *torus* $T$ is an affine variety isomorphic to $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$, where $T$ inherits a group structure from the isomorphism.

Now, my understanding of the definition of an affine variety, as per Hartshorne is a subset $A$ of affine $n$-space over an algebraically closed field $k$, such that $A = Z(B)$, i.e. $A$ is the zero-locus of some set $B\subset k[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

My question is, why is it stated that $(\mathbb{C}^*)^n$ is an affine variety? What set of polynomials is it the zero-locus of?

In particular, if $n=1$, then the only algebraic sets are finite sets, so how can $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ be an algebraic set if it is infinite?

Now, I suspect that *affine variety* should maybe be just *variety* as per Hartshorne's definition in Hartshorne page 15 where he defined a *variety* to be any affine, quasi-affine, projective, or quasi-projective variety. And thus together with morphisms between varieties we have the category of varieties.

Also I talked to some other people who know more about algebraic geometry who seems to not understand why there is confusion, since apparently they have a more general and abstract definition of a variety than merely as zero-loci. Whereas I understand that maybe after I've read enough of Hartshorne I may resolve this issue, the prerequisites listed for this particular chapter of *Toric Varieties*, which is also another book by Cox, called *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* also only uses this "elementary" definition. Therefore I expect this question to be resolvable within the bounds of my current progress of Hartshorne.

Would glad to have any help, thanks.

Comment: For $n = 1$, for example, consider $\mathbb{C}^* = \{(x, y)\in \mathbb{C}^2:\, xy = 1\}$.

Comment: For $K$ algebraically closed $K^*$ is affine in the sense that $K^* \to  Z(xy-1), x \mapsto (x,1/x)$ is a birational map whose poles are outside of the domains. When considering $K= \mathbb{C}$ you may allow biholomorphic maps instead of just birational (so that $\mathbb{C}/2i \pi \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{C}^*$)